# Ubuntu 16.04LTS extended display not working

Tags: display, 16.04, hdmi, external-monitor

I recently upgraded my system from Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04LTS. But after the upgrade, my extended display is not being detected. I am connecting the second display through an HDMI port. I even tried **System settings > Displays >detect display**.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The issue was with the nvidia graphics driver. This can be fixed by following the steps below:

1. Run

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge ^nvidia
   ```
2. Run

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
   ```
3. Run

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Run

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-387
   ```

   For this, check what the latest version is... in my case as of January 2018 it's `nvidia-387`.

The graphics versions are [here on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

Reboot and your graphics issue should be fixed.

Comment: Could you post the lspci output? I solved the problem by upgrading the kernel to 4.5.2. but I use a dual graphics system with AMDGPU. Second display on HDMI.

Comment: @Mookey 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)

Comment: Cool. Hacking this into my 16.04 on a dell e6420 destroyed my lightdm resolution and I'm not able to login.

Comment: Does not work for me. I have a Alienware laptop and it often does not detect external monitor using hdmi out.

Comment: @ferdy, same here. How did you fix this?

Comment: @eskalera i think i removed the configuration .gconf or so in my home folder and re-adjusted everything again.

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package nvidia-364`

Comment: @mjp I re-installed nvidia-common, thats all the first command was removing on my system. If your system is stuck re-install it and reboot. I did re-install it before rebooting and the dual screen is working. This answer is not a good one but honestly I am not sure sure if just re-installing the nvidia-common was the solution

Comment: Instead of nvidia using `Nouveau display driver from xserver-video-nouveau` solved problem for me

Comment: I have ATI vega after run this command it worked
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa