# HDMI connected monitor not working after upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have see a couple similar questions with this problem, but none of the solutions have worked for me.

This is on an Asus laptop with a built-in graphics card. `lspci | grep VGA` shows:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
```

The output of `xrandr` doesn't detect anything with the monitor plugged in.

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y             axis) 345mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I have tried two things so far, installing an Nvidia driver as described here:

[Ubuntu 16.04LTS extended display not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764142/ubuntu-16-04lts-extended-display-not-working)

and upgrading the kernel as described in this blog post:

http://linuxdaddy.com/blog/install-kernel-4-4-on-ubuntu/

Neither had an effect. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly how, but I got it working. I uninstalled the Nvidia drivers and rebooted. My best guess is that the 4.4.8 kernel with the original drivers is what I needed.

Comment: you don't seem to have an nvidia card  anyway , try lspci | grep -i nv

Comment: You're correct. `lspci | grep -i nv ` doesn't find anything.