# Uninstall doesn't work for dual monitor issue

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I am trying to get dual monitor to work, but I can't seem to be able to delete all the drivers. When I reboot after [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764142/ubuntu-16-04lts-extended-display-not-working):

1.Run `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*`

2.Run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`

3.Run `sudo apt-get update`

4.Run `sudo apt-get install nvidia-367`

I still have the drivers when I open software and updates, and the second monitor does not show up. Please help. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You install the drivers and are surprised that they are installed? Run only the first command and there will be no proprietary drivers in your system, or you can choose X.Org, that will do the same.

Comment: I don't understand why 370 is installed since I installed 367. What do you mean by chose X.org?

Comment: 370 is not installed, it is available.