# Ubuntu 16.04, unable to detect hdmi monitor

Tags: 16.04, display, hdmi, external-monitor

I've been using an Ubuntu 16.04 laptop at work, adding an additional monitor via HDMI. Today the laptop has not recognized any displays plugged into the HDMI port. I booted into my windows install and the hdmi was functioning correctly.

When I got to displays > detect displays only my laptops built-in display shows

```
xrandr --listmonitors
```

returns

```
Monitors: 1
0: +*eDP1 1920/345x1080/194+0+0  eDP1
```

I've attempted a solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764142/ubuntu-16-04lts-extended-display-not-working).
This was not an issue until just today, and to my knowledge nothing has changed in the OS since then. I have run

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get upgrade

to ensure I have the latest updates.

I'm using an Asus Q551LB laptop with a Nvidia Geforce 940m integrated chip

Anyone have any idea how to troubleshoot this? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: The solution you linked is for Nvidia Graphcis cards. Please edit and update your question with the one you have. Also which laptop is it, etc.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I've updated the post with my machine and integrated graphics information.

Comment: Do the procedure again but this time install `nvidia-375`.

Comment: The issue still seems to persist @CelticWarrior. Note that when installing the driver it asked if I wanted to disable uefi secure boot. I selected no on that option. However it seems the driver still installed successfully.

Comment: Unsigned drivers tend to trigger that warning. Perhaps that's the problem. Try booting with secure boot disable to see how it goes.

Comment: unfortunately it is still not displaying @CelticWarrior.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51627/discussion-between-celticwarrior-and-alkarin).