# Xubuntu 16.04 LTS: HDMI-Display not working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xubuntu, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I did a complete fresh installation with Xubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. Unfortunately, my HDMI-display does not work. Everything fine using the live-usb. But after reboot and first boot of the fresh installed system, the HDMI-display says 'No signal' and goes standby. I've checked a few things. The system, as well as the live-usb, uses the nouveau-driver for my Nvidia GeForce GT 640.

First, I tried using the proprietary driver using the "additional driver"-application.
 -> crashed the whole system.
Then, I tried using the proprietary driver nvidia-304 using the command line.
 -> crashed the whole system.

Of course, I tried to ensure that the display is working fine. It goes with the live-usb, as mentioned before, and it goes with another laptop (also running the same live-usb).

After searching the internet for terms like "hdmi does not work xubuntu" or "xubuntu nvidia driver" I checked some hardware data:
Live-usb and my PC (after installation) are using the same nouveau-driver. The only difference I found is the kernel. Live-usb is using 4.4.0-31-generic and the installed system is using 4.4.0-64-generic.

*There was no problem under Xubuntu 14.04 LTS.*

The system detects the HDMI-display correctly, but don't send it any signal. When I open the display-settings everything looks fine. All displays are there and can be managed.

*Update: After the fourth or fifth re-installation the HDMI-display works now. But after the display is going off, because of energy-savings, its not coming back on-line after waking it up.*

**Some facts about my hardware:**
I'm using a dual-display setup with two Acer G246HL Bbid (One connected via DVI and the other connected via HDMI). The graphics is  Nvidia GeForce GT 640.

`lspci -v | perl -ne '/VGA/../^$/ and /VGA|Kern/ and print'` gets me

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 [GeForce GT 640] (rev) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Kernel driver in use: nouveau
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```

And `uname -r` gets me

```
4.4.0-31-generic
```

on live-usb and

```
4.4.0-64-generic
```

on fresh installed system.

`xrandr` gets me

```
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis yaxis) 531mm x 299mm
```

followed by a list of available resolutions.
When I do `apt list --installed | grep nouveau` it gets me

```
libdrm-nouveau2/xenial-updates,now 2.4.70-1~ubuntu16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
xserver-xorg-video-nouveau/xenial,now 1:1.0.12-1build2 amd64 [installed]
```

Doing it with `grep nvidia` gets no result.

I'm using Xubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 64bit-version with LVM-encryption.

**What I tried before:**
[Ubuntu 16.04LTS extended display not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764142/ubuntu-16-04lts-extended-display-not-working) 
https:// wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Grafikkarten/Nvidia/nvidia/ 
http:// askubuntu.com/questions/806720/hdmi-connected-monitor-not-working-after-upgrade-from-14-04-to-16-04 
https:// bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1574005

I've considered to install another kernel (4.4.25) using http://linuxdaddy.com/blog/install-kernel-4-4-on-ubuntu/. But didn't do it yet.

**Does anyone knows a solution for that kind problem in general? At the moment I will prevent my display from going in energy-savings-caused standby to have a little workaround.**