# Second display not detected nor usable

Tags: 16.04, display, hdmi, external-monitor

Today I installed Ubuntu 16.04.2, I want to use extended display alongside my laptop, but it does not detect and show the other display. I searched and followed [this other question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764142/ubuntu-16-04lts-extended-display-not-working) but it's deprecated and no longer works - when I try to install the package mentioned it's not located

What should I do to have my second display working?

Comment: Did you do all the steps from the accepted answer?

Comment: @M.Becerra yes, i did all as told in that answer

Comment: Try `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nvidia-364`

Comment: @M.Becerra, This i already followed, but throws the error "E: Unable to locate package nvidia-364" .

Comment: It is correct, such package doesn't exist in that repository. As you can see [here](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=). If you still want to fix your problem with the monitor, post a new question about it.

Comment: @M.Becerra which version then should i install to get things working,

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install nvidia-commons`and reboot

Comment: @M.Becerra , it again throws the same error , E: Unable to locate package nvidia-commons

Comment: I updated the latest intel Kabylake and Broxton drivers as suggested by this http://askubuntu.com/questions/832524/updated-kernel-to-4-8-now-missing-firmware-warnings/832528#832528 and the issue resolved. Thanks

Comment: Im glad you managed! Do you want to add such solution as an answer?

Comment: @M.Becerra I am new here and am not aware of specific rules, since this answer helped so i would say yes. Otherwise as you suggest.

Comment: I encourage you to try, once you are dont, give me a hint, and I can try help you edit it or improve your answer, if needed :)