# Nvidia-364 package not in laptop, disallowing me to find my external monitor

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, external-monitor

I was on my laptop, and I decided to use my external monitor to enlarge the screen. It wasn't showing the display, even after I pressed the **detect displays** button. So I followed the instructions on this website:
[Ubuntu 16.04LTS extended display not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764142/ubuntu-16-04lts-extended-display-not-working)
and I followed the steps. On the last step, I had to do the command

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-364
```

and it showed me this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old' in directory '/etc/apt
/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unable to locate package nvidia-364
```

I don't know what to do now because I don't have the nvidia-364 package.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks, Vaibhav

P.S I have a Ubuntu 16.04 Lenovo Thinkpad.